# CentOS 8 stream

Tags: centos8, wallaby

dnf --enablerepo=centos-openstack-wallaby -y upgrade
CentOS-8 - Ceph Nautilus                                  63  B/s |  38  B     00:00
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'centos-ceph-nautilus': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update your CentOS 8 Stream, you need to change the mirrors to vault.centos.org

Step 1: Go to the /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory

```
# cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
```

Step 2: Run the below commands

```
# sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
# sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
```

Now run your dnf command.